# Power BI Reports using Azure Time Series Insights - error with aggregation

Tags: powerbi, azure-timeseries-insights

I am trying to create Power BI reports from Time Series Insights and when I use the option 'Aggregate data' I get the error:  "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: interval Path 'aggregateSeries'."

I can use the option 'Raw events' for the same Time Series Insights view without error.

What can cause this error?

Comment: Are you following this doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/how-to-connect-power-bi? 
Can you check this solution and see if it helps: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Value-cannot-be-null-Parameter-name-stream/td-p/1352313

Comment: Hi, Do you mind sharing the query. Please make sure the filed ```"interval": "PT03M"``` is not empty.